# Solr extension for TYPO3 10. Get image URL

Tags: solr, typo3, typoscript

I need to get the URL of an image from the indexing of SOLR for displaying the image on the results (solr 11 and typo3 10.4)

I've got this example from the News extension, but it does not work for me.

```
image_stringS = FILES
        image_stringS {
            references {
                table = tx_myext_domain_model_shop
                uid.field = uid
                fieldName = the_field_with_the_reference_on_my_table
            }

            begin = 0
            maxItems = 1

            renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
            renderObj {
                file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                file.maxW = 330
                #wrap = |
            }
        }
```

This is my ts

```
plugin.tx_solr {
    search {
        initializeWithEmptyQuery = 1
        showResultsOfInitialEmptyQuery = 1
        faceting = 1
        faceting {
            facets {
                Branches {
                    label = Branches
                    field = branches_stringM
                }
                Brands {
                    label = Brands
                    field = brands_stringM
                }
            }
        }
    }
    index.queue {
        shops = 1
        shops {
            table = tx_myext_domain_model_shop
            additionalWhereClause = deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0
            fields {
                title = COA
                title {
                    5 = TEXT
                    5 {
                        field = name
                        noTrimWrap = || |
                    }
                }

                image_intM = SOLR_RELATION
                image_intM {
                    localField = thumbnail
                    foreignLabelField = uid
                    multiValue = 1
                }

                description_stringS = TEXT
                description_stringS {
                    field = description
                }
                name_stringS = TEXT
                name_stringS {
                    field = name
                }

                branches_stringM = SOLR_RELATION
                branches_stringM {
                    localField = branches
                    foreignLabelField = title
                    multiValue = 1
                }

                brands_stringM = SOLR_RELATION
                brands_stringM {
                    localField = brands
                    foreignLabelField = title
                    multiValue = 1
                }

                openfrom1_stringS = SOLR_RELATION
                openfrom1_stringS {
                    localField = opening_times
                    foreignLabelField = open_from_1
                }

                opento1_stringS = SOLR_RELATION
                opento1_stringS {
                    localField = opening_times
                    foreignLabelField = open_to_1
                }

                openfrom2_stringS = SOLR_RELATION
                openfrom2_stringS {
                    localField = opening_times
                    foreignLabelField = open_from_1
                }

                opento2_stringS = SOLR_RELATION
                opento2_stringS {
                    localField = opening_times
                    foreignLabelField = open_to_1
                }

                image_stringS = FILES
                image_stringS {
                    references {
                        table = tx_myext_domain_model_shop
                        uid.field = uid
                        fieldName = thumbnail
                    }

                    begin = 0
                    maxItems = 1

                    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
                    renderObj {
                        file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                        file.maxW = 330
                        #wrap = |
                    }
                }

                url = COA
                url {
                    65 = CASE
                    65.key.field = type
                    65.default = TEXT
                    65.default {
                        typolink.parameter.cObject = CASE
                        typolink.parameter.cObject {
                            key.cObject = TEXT
                            66 = TEXT
                            66.value = {$pages.PIDs.shop.detailPid}

                            default = TEXT
                            default.value = {$pages.PIDs.shop.detailPid}
                        }
                        typolink.additionalParams = &tx_myext_plugin[controller]=Shop&tx_myext_plugin[action]=show&tx_myext_plugin[shop]={field:uid}
                        typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
                        typolink.useCacheHash = 1
                        typolink.returnLast = url
                    }
                }

                content = SOLR_CONTENT
                content {
                    cObject = COA
                    cObject {
                        10 = TEXT
                        10 {
                            field = name
                        }
                        15.value = &nbsp;
                        20 = TEXT
                        20 {
                            field = description
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, I end up using a ViewHelper and getting the sys_file object from "image_intM" but I still want to know why that example does not work in my case.

Comment: I do add the UID of the file reference and do the image rendering via fluid view helper. Would that be an option?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that because I manage to get the sys_file_reference UID but I didn't manage to call the file from the helper hehe, if you have a link that helps me to do that I will be grateful (noob here). But either way, it will be cool and 'simple' to do it straight from the ts.

Comment: I do this mostly like your example with `image_intM` but without `foreignLabelField = uid`. See: https://gitlab.typo3.org/services/t3o-sites/typo3.org/typo3.org/-/blob/develop/extensions/t3org_layout/Configuration/TypoScript/Ext/Solr.typoscript#L82

Comment: Thank you! I see that in your t3org_layout/Resources/Private/Partials/Solr/Result/Item/tx_news_domain_model_news.html file you are just printing the "{document.media_intM.0}". You are not processing it with a viewhelper.